# MYSQL query minus operator not working

Tags: mysql, sql, unsigned, bigint, outofrangeexception

Looked up of all questions about error with minus operator in MYSQL and can't find solution.
all given solutions not working. 
i`m trying to get difference between Units In Stock and Units On Order
and my query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT   UnitsInStock - UnitsOnOrder as 'Difference'
        FROM products ";
```

why i got this error?

```
 Warning: mysqli_query(): (22003/1690): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range
```

Comment: What are the values of `UnitsInStock` and `UnitsOnOrder` which generate this error?  It sounds like the subtraction is overflowing the unsigned numeric value.  (Perhaps producing a negative value?)

Comment: yes it  producing a negative value to

Comment: I don't understand why people find it so difficult to put their error message into the SO search box? That almost always finds questions with answers. Do you really think you're the first one to get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT CAST(UnitsInStock AS SIGNED) - CAST(UnitsOnOrder AS SIGNED) as 'Difference' FROM products
```

Comment: What if you do this: `CAST(UnitsInStock AS SIGNED) - CAST(UnitsOnOrder AS SIGNED)`

Comment: @user3208511 If it works you can accept this answer and maybe upvote it. :D

Comment: edit your answer please. you forgot second CAST

Comment: @user3208511 Ooopppssss! :)